# xamarin binding variable to label using timer event

Tags: xamarin, binding

I want to **binding** a variable to a label which as a children in a grid.
the variable changed with a ***timer event***.pls check my code help me found out where i am wrong.I can see the label init **value** is **0**,but it won't update when the variable do.

---

```
public class DevicePage : ContentPage
{
    IDevice device;
    Label testLb = new Label();
    System.Timers.Timer  testtimer;
    Grid gridView;
    byte testt { get; set; } = 0;
    GetSendData communicate;
    private byte _maintext;  
    public byte MainText
    {
        get
        {
            return _maintext;
        }
        set
        {
            _maintext = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public DevicePage(IDevice currDevice)
    {
        device = currDevice;
        this.Title = "Status";
        testtimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        testtimer.Interval = 1000;
        testtimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
        testtimer.Enabled = true;

        gridView = new Grid();
        testLb.Text = testt.ToString();
        testLb.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, ".");
        testLb.BindingContext = MainText;
        gridView.Children.Add(testLb, 0, 0);
        this.Content = gridView;
    }
    private void OnTimedEvent(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {

        MainText += 1;
    }
```

Comment: you cannot just call OnPropertyChanged - your class must implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: after I implement INotifyPropertyChanged,testLb won't update either.But I change testLb.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, ".");
        testLb.BindingContext = MainText; to testLb.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "MainText");
        testLb.BindingContext = this;  It works!

Answer (score 0):

after I implement INotifyPropertyChanged,testLb won't update either.But I change testLb.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "."); testLb.BindingContext = MainText; to testLb.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "MainText"); testLb.BindingContext = this; It works!